# PrintDialog ToPage should be less than the page count

Tags: vb.net, printing, syncfusion

I recently upgraded my computer to Windows 10, and now one of the programs is acting weird since the upgrade. 
Trying to print a page range out of a PDF, and when I print pages 1 to 100 (out of 477 pages) I get an error saying `ToPage should be less than the page count` even though 100 is less than 477.
If I skip the page range part and just have it print all of the pages, it works fine.

```
Sub PrintToPaperSync(ByVal InputfilePath As String, Optional ByVal DeleteAfter As Boolean = False)
    On Error GoTo sError

    Dim tError As String = ""
    Dim toPage As Integer = 0

    Console.WriteLine("PrintToPaper " & InputfilePath)
    Dim File As String = Split(InputfilePath, "\")(Split(InputfilePath, "\").Length - 1)
    Dim viewer As New Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.PdfViewer.PdfDocumentView
    viewer.Load(InputfilePath)
    Dim print As New System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog()

    print.Document = viewer.PrintDocument
    print.Document.DocumentName = File

    'print 100 pages at a time
    Do While toPage < viewer.PageCount
        print.Document.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = Drawing.Printing.PrintRange.SomePages
        print.Document.PrinterSettings.FromPage = toPage + 1
        toPage += 100
        print.Document.PrinterSettings.ToPage = IIf(toPage < viewer.PageCount, toPage, viewer.PageCount)

        tError = "From: " & print.Document.PrinterSettings.FromPage & " | To: " & print.Document.PrinterSettings.ToPage & " | PageCount: " & viewer.PageCount & " - "
        print.Document.Print()

        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

    viewer.Unload()
    viewer.Dispose()

    Console.WriteLine("Printing: " & InputfilePath)

    Exit Sub
sError:
    Dim ErrorStr As String = ErrorToString()
    WriteLine("PrintToPaper " & tError & " " & InputfilePath & " - " & ErrorStr)
End Sub
```

Full text of the error:
`PrintToPaper From: 1 | To: 100 | PageCount: 477 -  F:\Process\LogTag-10-30-15-104122.pdf - ToPage should be less than the page count`

We want to only print 100 pages at a time, because the printer begins to slow down after 100 pages for some reason.

Comment: For testing I'd suggest you convert this to a try catch block and print out the real exception that you are getting - it will likely go a long way to finding out what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This printing problem is caused due to the issue with Syncfusion Control. You can contact the Syncfusion Software Support team to get the issue resolved. Please follow the below link to contact Syncfusion Support Team

[Click Here](https://www.syncfusion.com/account/login)